# Docker error: Unable to locate package git

Tags: git, docker, ubuntu, apt

I'm using an image `nginx` which is based on `dockerfile/ubuntu`. On attaching to the docker container's shell

```
docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash
```

I want to do a `git pull` so I tried installing `git` but `apt` is unable to find the package:

```
root@a71e45d5cd40:/# apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package git
```

How can we install `git` from that image and why is it missing?

---

**cat /etc/apt/sources.list**

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian wheezy main
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian wheezy-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates main
deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ wheezy nginx
```

**cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/***

```
cat: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*: No such file or directory
```

**apt-cache madison git**

```
N: Unable to locate package git
```

Comment: `root@....` you are already the super user, so sudo doesn't exist afaik.

Comment: @SeanKenny thanks, let me rephrase the question

Comment: show `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`, `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` and `apt-cache madison git` for diagnostic.

Comment: Given that this is docker, it's possible that git isn't a package 'registered' (for want of a better word) with apt in `/etc/apt/sources.list(.d/)`. I'm not 100% sure how Docker works in that regard.

Comment: @DmitryVerkhoturov Updated question which the output of those commands

Answer (score 173, accepted):

This is happening because the apt repository is not yet updated, it is common practice to clean your apt repositories and tmp files after creating an image, which your base image is probably doing.

To fix this, you are going to want to run `apt-get update` prior to installing git, it is good practice to combine the update and install command at the same time to bust cache on the update if the install line changes:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
```

Using `-y` is convenient to automatically answer yes to all the questions.

Comment: Thanks that works! Btw, how do we clean the apt repo and tmp files if we want to build a new image?

Comment: At the end of your Dockerfile, something like this: `RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*`

Comment: Just a note here, cleaning repositories does not help with image size unless you clean on the same layer (command) that you add the files. btrfs will store the layers with all the files

Comment: I have this : /bin/sh: apt-get: not found  ?!

Comment: Do you have apt-get in your image? Does your distro use apt-get or another package manager?