# Rename folder on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have created a repository on Linux where one folder name contains a colon (':'). Now I want to `clone` it to a Windows system. Because a colon is not allowed in path names on Windows I get the message:

> error: Invalid path (...)

I don't have access to a Linux system now. Is there a possibility to rename the folder via the GitHub web interface?

Note: I am the only one using this repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [move a file in a new location from GitHub API](https://help.github.com/articles/moving-a-file-to-a-new-location/), which isn't practical if you have a lot of them.

An alternative way is to use [docker/machine](https://github.com/docker/machine) (see [get started](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/)) to

- pull any ubuntu image,
- [make a Dockerfile installing git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29929714/6309),
- `docker run -it --rm` this new image,
- clone your repo there,
- do a `git mv`, add, commit and push back.

Comment: Thanks. Since both answers so far seems to indicate renaming a folder via the Github web interface is not possible, I will follow the suggestion of both authors and use a Linux virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to rename directory, since Git doesn't operate directories. But you can try to move all files from that directory to a new one (empty directory won't be created by `git clone`). How to move file is described in the [Github documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/moving-a-file-to-a-new-location/).

Comment: Thanks. I thought about renaming, but I had two objections: 1. From the web interface I thought I could not go a directory down. (It seems you can with prepending `../`). 2. It is a lot of work. But, if there is not a way to rename the folder I might do just that.

Comment: Yes, it's a lot of work and should be last thing to do if you have a lot of files. I like @VonC's suggestion. Docker should do the trick.